# How do current probes load a circuit?

Tags: current, current-measurement, measurement, load, probe

It's usual to talk about loading a circuit when measuring voltage, with a voltmeter or with a voltage probe and an oscilloscope. It can be seen as putting an impedance in parallel to the element whose voltage is to be measured.

However, I don't understand in which way exactly does a **current probe** load a circuit. Can it be seen as an impedance in series to the branch of the circuit being measured? What does the value of the impedance depend on?

EDIT:

Thanks to the comments below I realized that the question was not specific enough. The mechanism of the current probes I'm interested in are those which basically make use of a transformer to sense the strength of a magnetic field caused by a changing current in the circuit. Something like this:

[image]

How do these load a circuit? Also, if a Hall effect device is added to the probe to detect DC as well, does the mechanism in which it loads the circuit change?

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you edit your question to give an example of the type of current probe you are thinking of. A photo and link to a datasheet would improve it further.

Comment: @Transistor I didn't know there were many types, just AC and AC+DC. Is that what you mean or is there another sort of classification? I'm not specifically interested in any particular probe, I was wondering if maybe there was some simple intuition as in the case of passive voltage probes.

Comment: The main ones are Hall effect sensors, magnetically-coupled probes, and shunt resistance based probes. The mechanisms by which they load the circuit are different.

Comment: @ThePhoton The only ones I know about are those described in [Tektronik's ABC of Probes](http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/ABCprobes_s.pdf). I'll edit the question to ask about these specifically.

Comment: Adding a ferrite sleeve will add inductance and will limit , by higher impedance, the bandwidth of the sensor . But usually an air gapped sleeve is used for AC with lower inductance and a non-gapped ferrite for down to DC response which has degaussing features and null balance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I didn't know there were many types, just AC and AC+DC. Is that what you mean or is there another sort of classification?

There are several common techniques for measuring current. The standard terminology is to discuss the "burden" the meter places on the circuit and to minimise the loading effect the burden should be kept as low as possible.

**Shunt resistor**

[image]

*Figure 1. A 500 A - 100 mV shunt. Source: [RAmmeter](https://www.rammeter.com/ram-meter-b500a100-500-amp-100-dcmv-dc-current-shunt.php).*

- This is placed in series with the load being measured.
- It will cause a small voltage drop and this voltage can be measured and converted to current by Ohm's law.
- Shunts can be used to measure AC or DC.
- Note the two large bolt holes for the high current connections and the two small screws for the voltage measurement connections to avoid measuring voltage drops across the current connection bolts.

**Current transformer**

[image]

*Figure 2. A current transformer with standard 5 A output. Source: [TestGuy](https://testguy.net/content/264-6-electrical-tests-for-Current-Transformers-explained).*

- The primary of the CT is in series with the load being monitored and the secondary goes to a measuring circuit - in the old days, typically an AC meter.
- They only work on AC.
- The burden seen by the circuit is the secondary burden divided by the turns ratio squared.
- Often the primary consists of only one turn.

**Hall sensor**

[image]

*Figure 3. A crude Hall sensor. Source: [Connecting Industry](http://www.connectingindustry.com/electronics/hall-effect-current-sensors-their-role-in-advance-power-distribution.aspx).*

- These are like a CT but contain a Hall sensor in the ferrite core and this measures the magnetic flux induced by the primary and so can measure AC and DC.

See also Rowgowski coils and PCB current measuring probes for more interesting reading.

Comment: Thanks for the so detailed answer. So, if the probe goes into, for instance, a spectrum analyzer whose input impedance is 50 Ohm and the secondary has 50 turns while the primary just 1, the loading would be of 1 Ohm? Is this correct? Also, in the case of the Hall sensor, does the loading mechanism change or is it the same as in the just-AC ones?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the current probe style, the probes are magnetically coupled. The magnetic sensor is high impedance and very little energy is lost to sensing the magnetic field of the wire.

Most current probes could be modeled as inductors or transformers, with the impedance depending on the magnetic coupling between the wire being sensed. Since almost no current is lost in the sensor (because if it's a hall effect, its ran into an amplifier with a high impedance input. If it's a coil, in almost all cases it's also ran into a high impedance amplifier. ). The clamp material would probably account for most of the loss in the system from resistive heating.

Comment: If it's a coil it is **certainly not** run into a high impedance amplifier - it's run into a low impedance burden.

Comment: Can you give an example? All the current probes I've seen are amplified (or have a hall effect sensor)

Comment: CTs require a low impedance burden resistor. You should be able to find stuff about this all over the net.

Comment: The CT's that measure 100's of amps do that, never used one.